# How to pass parameter from query string from view to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

While in `Create` View I have this link: `http://localhost:17697/Reports/Create?personId=2`.

Inside a view I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click `Save` button I submit the form and invoke `POST Create` action method. I would also pass there this `2` from `?personId=2` in query string from link inside a view to `POST Create` method.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Text")] Report report) {
            // I WANT TO GET personId=2 from query string here
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                db.Reports.Add(report);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(report);
        }
```

Will adding this inside a form is correct approach? `@Html.Hidden( @Html.Encode("personId"))`

Comment: Why woudln't you just have the person id as a property of the model?

Comment: get personid in post controller as public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Text")] Report report,int?personId)

Answer (score 2):

Add it as a parameter...

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Text")] Report report, int personId){
}
```

Comment: So I do not have to @Html.Encode inside a form and hide it?

Comment: It did work.   I wanted to do it hard way to insert this data into `ViewData` and forgot about basics.